# Loading All The Content And Then Slicing It To Make Pagination, Bad For The Performance? JS

Tags: javascript, html

The website should have 1000 checkboxes and 1000 labels at least, now there is 12 in the demo.
I made it to load all the elements and then slice them to make a pagination.
Does that hurt the performance in the future when there will be 2000 elements loaded with the foreach loop.
If it does, I hope there is a solution for that.
Here is my code:

```
// Load Words Call To Action
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function () {
    fetch('http://localhost:5000/manage/letters/getAll')
    .then(response => response.json())
    .then(data => {
        loadLetters(data['data']);
        tran();
    });
});

// Load Letters Function
let lettersHtml;
function loadLetters(data) {
    const letters = document.querySelector('.letters');

    if (data.length === 0) {
        letters.innerHTML = "<p class='no-data'>لا يوجد محتوى</p>";
        return;
    }

    lettersHtml = "";

    data.forEach(function ({id, letter, file, clid, lid}) {
        lettersHtml += `<input type="checkbox" class="check-letter" id="${clid}" value = "${id}" onchange="tran()">`;
        lettersHtml += `<label for="${clid}" class="letter card" id="${lid}">${letter}</label>`;
        
        console.log("0");
    });
    letters.innerHTML = lettersHtml;
    console.log("1");

    // Calling Pagination
    pagina();
}
```

Comment: Performance is a complex topic, e.g. loading everything at once will make the initial load slower, but changing the "page" of data faster. Unless you have a specific situation you are aiming for or trying to avoid, I'm not sure we can answer this.

Comment: There are many libraries that do what you have written here ..  As @DBS has stated .. The initial load is slow, but the pagination is faster.  The alternative is to grab each page from the back end and serve `X` results at a time.  This method will make initial load faster, but will slightly slow the pagination process depending on network speed.